# while loop issues in PYthon + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

can you tell me why my while loop isn't working, please? I get no error message, it just runs once.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time

PATH = "/Users/csongordoma/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
current_page = 1
driver.get('https://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+lakas+budapest?page=' + str(current_page))
data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price', 'Address', 'Size', 'Rooms', 'URL', 'Labels'])

listings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__card')

while current_page < 10:
    for listing in listings:
        data['Price'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.price')[0].text
        data['Address'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__address')[0].text
        data['Size'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__parameters')[0].text
        data['Labels'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__labels')[0].text
        data['URL'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.listing__link.js-listing-active-area')[0].get_attribute('href')
        df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        current_page += 1

print(len(listings))
print(df)

#   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[. = 'Következő oldal']").click()

driver.quit()
```

the output is a good data frame of 20 items which is one page's worth. on the [website](https://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+lakas+budapest?page=1) I'm trying to scrape. Set the limit at 10 cycles to not overload anyone, but ideally, I want to run through all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just arrange the code inside your while loop and indent the currentpage to the outer loop. I added a try except in case of any errors and webdriver waits for consistency of getting elements after driver.get.

```
current_page = 1

data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price', 'Address', 'Size', 'Rooms', 'URL', 'Labels'])

while current_page < 10:
    driver.get('https://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+lakas+budapest?page=' + str(current_page))
    try:
        listings=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.listing__card")))
        for listing in listings:
            data['Price'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.price')[0].text
            data['Address'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__address')[0].text
            data['Size'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__parameters')[0].text
            data['Labels'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__labels')[0].text
            data['URL'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.listing__link.js-listing-active-area')[0].get_attribute('href')
            df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
    except:
        print('Error')
    current_page += 1

print(len(listings))
print(df)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```